# Wait before execute next line in bat

Tags: batch-file, command, command-line-arguments

I want something like this-

```
@echo off
echo Wait for 10 sec
timeout /t 10
echo Thanks for waiting
```

But this shows timeout is not recognized as an internal or external command. I want the program to wait 10 sec before showing "Thanks for waiting" .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

timeout is not available on all versions of windows
Also `choice` has a timeout-option, but also not available on all versions of windows.
This works on all versions (except Win 3.1 because it had no network):

```
ping -n 11 localhost >nul
```